# Json-server in Azure?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure

I have been using json-server in Node.js simulating a REST api to separate the data and the app in my javascript app. I am now trying to publish the app with Microsoft Azure so that I can share it with my friends. The data was just simple .JSON files but the might get larger.

Can I create a real REST api and do I do that though a database like SQL which is available in Azure? Or should I just use the JSON-files loaded into my javascript from the start?

Is the resource explorer (http://resources.azure.com) a way to add data to my app?

I am not sure how to proceed or how to search for the correct answer since I don't know the correct terms (sorry if this question is already asked).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you want to know where to store the json data?

Comment: @PeterBons I understand now that I should probably use a databse to store my data. I have made a table under localdb in phpmyadmin though the "mysql in app" section on my webb app on azure. I read that the best way is to use php to generate json from my database. I'm just trying to connect to the DB though a php file at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource explorer (http://resources.azure.com) is a database workbench, it is used to manage the resources(service tier) on Azure subscription.

And your question is a little wide to give out a detailed or step by step answer.

Before you deploy your node.js application to Azure. You can try to implement with the database services on Azure at first. There are lot of databases you can chose on Azure, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/#pivot=services&panel=databases for more info.

For Eample,
You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-nodejs for how to work with Azure Database for PostgreSQL in Node.js.
And refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs for how to deploy a Node.js application to Azure Web  Apps.